# Generating unique solutions for N-Queens

Tags: n-queens

I am trying to write a code to generate unique solutions for N-Queens. I am able to generate correct solution for N = 4 and 6 (but not for other cases of N) and have eliminated the cases of generation of non-distinct solutions due to rotation by 180 and 90 degrees. The problem lies in my understanding of how to eliminate other redundant cases.

For example, for N = 5, I should get 2 unique solutions but I am generating 3. The 2 redundant solutions, out of which one is to be eliminated are (the 3rd solution is correct):

Q----                 Q----

--Q--   ---Q-

----Q   -Q---

-Q---   ----Q

---Q-   --Q--

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

Comment: I am having trouble in setting a condition for symmetricity of solutions.